# why fabricjs kclass fromobject returning undefined on new version?

Tags: undefined, fabricjs

yesterday i have changed fabricjs version in our application. suddenly kclass.fromObject returning undefined.

my previous version is 1.7.22 and currently using 3.6.1   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.1/fabric.min.js

kclass.fromobject returning undefined. but objects[i] has data.

```
> var klass = fabric.util.getKlass(objects[i].type); 
> console.log(klass.fromObject(objects[i]));  //returning undefined on 3.6.1 
> fabricObj.add(klass.fromObject(objects[i]));
```

could you please let me know how to fix this issue?

Here is the screenshot

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no way to guess what's going wrong unless you show what `objects[i]` is.

Comment: i have uploaded screenshots please check once. @shkaper

Comment: please you can check here my code.
version 1.7.22 fabricjs
https://jsfiddle.net/hnsdvkqg/

version 3.6.1

https://jsfiddle.net/kphebdgx/

Answer (score 1):

Your `objects` array contains just plain javascript objects that represent serialized Fabric objects (like path, circles, whatever).

Before rendering these plain javascript objects you need to transform them in Fabric objects. This process is called deserialization. 
Your code does it, but only the if the `async` property of the variable `klass` is true. 
It happens here:

```
var klass = fabric.util.getKlass(objects[i].type);
if (klass.async) {
    klass.fromObject(objects[i], function (img) {
        canvas1.add(img);
    });
}
```

The object is deserialized, passed as an argument to the callback function and then added to the canvas, and this is great.

The problem is in the else branch of your conditional, where nothing of that happens. The only code present is this:

```
else {
    console.log(objects[i]);
    canvas1.add((objects[i]));
}
```

Here you are trying to add the plain object to the canvas, and that triggers an error.
One simple solution is to remove the `if / else` and always execute the deserialization step. If for other reasons you need to maintain the `if / else` conditional, you can simply deserialize the object in the else path too.

Here is a [working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zpou5sgr/) that preserves the conditional.

Why did it work in the previous version of Fabric? It is hard to say. Maybe that type of object was marked as async, so triggering the right path. Or maybe the `canvas.add` method was automatically deserializing javascript objects.